# How to get lowest bar between a range

Tags: pine-script

In pine-script `lowest(x)` gets lowest value from last `x` bars.
How do i specify a range ? I want to get lowest between `current-n` to `x` bars

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a better way to do it but I would do it this way.

Get the lowest close for the previous 10 bars.

`lowestlast10 = lowest(close,10)`

Then look at the value say 20 bars ago using historical reference []. Which would give me the lowest close for 10 bars starting from 20 bars back. So the lowest close from 20 to 30 bars back.

`lowestbetwen20_30 = lowestlast10[20]`